# unable to delete unknown file named ";"

Tags: linux, macos, shell, unix, vi

I'm using mac os. I noticed there's a unknown file named ";" and it's not deletable.
I tried:

```
rm ;
```

And the error message is:

```
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...
       unlink file
```

this an empty file, not directory. Could anyone explain to me what's that is and how to remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`;` is used as a delimiter in shell between two query.
`echo toto; echo tata` will run echo toto then echo tata.

Do delete the file, you have to escape it:

```
rm ';'
```

This way `;` is not interpreted as a keyword by your shell, but instead given as an argument to `rm`

Comment: Another way (not as good, and certainly not necessary in this scenario): `rm -i *` - say 'n' to everything you want to keep and 'y' to the one (or more) you don't.

Comment: I think a backslash ( \ ) works as an escape char, too.